# Title, description, and logo

Tags: 2013, web-part-page, title

I may be overthinking this, but I created a web part page on SharePoint 2013 and named it Home.

The new page replaced an existing page called Home.  I changed the name of the old page to Homeold that way the new page can maintain the same URL.

I set the new page as the Home page, but the Title still reads Home, even though in the Title, description, and logo area the Title reads a different name.

I don't want to edit the page and change the title because it'll then change the URL, I just want to change the Look and Feel and rename the title.

Any help on a fix for this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the page will always show as a title at the top part of the screen. So there is no OOTB way of dealing with it.

If it's a real issue - you can add a Script editor webpart or a Content Editor Werbpart with a small script that will change the title. It feels hacky to me though:

```
<script>
  $("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").innerText = "<Whatever Page name you want>"
</script>
```

Comment: Thank  you for the response.  I don't mind the name of the page showing as a title at the top.  The issue is that the page is named "HOME." The word "HOME" shows up on the title of the page.  I should, per theory, be able to change the title in the "Title, description, and logo link in Site Settings, Look and Feel.  Naming the title to something different should change the name from "HOME" to the new name, but it does not.  The description is there, but the title name still shows "HOME."

Comment: I will try the script though.  Thanks again.